# Numbering for a whole system of equations

Tags: numbering, alignat

I want to keep the layout but only one number for the whole system of equations in the middle of them. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}\label{ali:rekursion}
1&=a_{0}b_{0}&\quad\Rightarrow b_{0}&=a_{0}^{-1}\\
0&=a_{0}b_{1}+a_{1}b_{0}&\Rightarrow b_{1}&=-a_{1}a_{0}^{-2}\\
0&=a_{0}b_{2}+a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{0}&\Rightarrow b_{2}&=a_{1}^{2}a_{0}^{-3}-a_{2}a_{0}^{-2}\\
&\vdots &&\vdots
\end{alignat}

In equation~(\ref{ali:rekursion})...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `alignedat` inside `equation`. I added a couple of adjustments for having the vertical dots centered with respect to the equals signs and not so far away from the last line.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{ali:rekursion}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
1&=a_{0}b_{0}                       &\quad&\Rightarrow\quad & b_{0}&=a_{0}^{-1}\\
0&=a_{0}b_{1}+a_{1}b_{0}            &     &\Rightarrow      & b_{1}&=-a_{1}a_{0}^{-2}\\
0&=a_{0}b_{2}+a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{0} &     &\Rightarrow      &
  b_{2}&=a_{1}^{2}a_{0}^{-3}-a_{2}a_{0}^{-2}\\[-1ex]
&\vdotswithin{=} &&&&\vdotswithin{=}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

In equation~\eqref{ali:rekursion}...
\end{document}
```

Note that `\vdotswithin` requires `mathtools`.

I used one pair of columns more in order to get equal spacing around the double arrows.

Instead of manually adding parentheses, use `\eqref` instead of `\ref`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for making the distinction between alignat and alignedat, with the latter being able to exist inside the equation environment.  Saved me a lot of time researching why I was getting an error using alignat with the equation environment!